# Ruby On Rails - Devise - sessions_controller : undefined 'build_resource'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm a beginner with Ruby On Rails and I tried all I can but I can't solve my problem...

I use devise and I want to use recaptcha on the sign_in and the sign_up pages.
So I overwrite the devise sessions and registrations controllers to make my own create method in which I check the validity of the captcha.

So, I made like above:

In my own registrations_controller.rb:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    if verify_recaptcha
      super
    else
      build_resource
      resource.errors.clear
      resource.errors.add(:base, "Wrong captcha, try again.")
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

In my own sessions_controller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController 
  def create
    if verify_recaptcha
      super
    else
      build_resource
      resource.errors.clear
      resource.errors.add(:base, "Wrong captcha, try again.")
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

For the sign_up page, it works well, but for the sign_in page I have a problem because the method 'buil_resource' is protected in the Devise sessions controller.
(I read this : [Ruby Devise, SessionsController.create, json - getting NameError: undefined 'build_resource'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758288/ruby-devise-sessionscontroller-create-json-getting-nameerror-undefined-bui))
I tried all the solutions I found but none works --> I don't know what to do now...

I'll be grateful for any help on this point : by what can I replace this method ?

**---------------------------------------------- EDIT ----------------------------------------------**

I use the code from the `new` method of `Devise::SessionsController` like above and it works pretty well:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController 
  def create
    if verify_recaptcha
      super
    else
      self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
      #flash[:alert] = "Wrong captcha, try again."
      resource.errors.clear
      resource.errors.add(:base, "Wrong captcha, try again.")
      respond_with_navigational(resource, serialize_options(resource)) { render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

Now, the only thing is I don't see the error `"Wrong captcha, try again"` if I type a wrong captcha.

I have the solution to use `flash[:alert]` like in the commented line but it's not printed the same way so if someone know why I don't see the resource errors, please give it to me ! :)

Comment: You tried putting `include Devise::Controllers::InternalHelpers` inside your sessions controller, and that didn't work?  Because that is supposed to give you access to build_resource outside of the RegistrationsController

Comment: Thanks for your response but I already tried and I get the error : `unitialized constant Devise::Controllers::InternalHelpers`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController 
  def create
    if verify_recaptcha
      super
    else
      self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
      resource.valid?
      resource.errors.add(:base, "Wrong captcha, try again.")
      respond_with_navigational(resource, serialize_options(resource)) { render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

My problem was that only captcha was in `resource.errors`, but other attributes not, so I'm validate resource by `resource.valid?` after creating object and everything is fine now.