# Devise - Sign In with Ajax

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, warden

Is here any possibility to modify devise **SessionsController** for ajax communication?

### Edit

I found the solution, and posted it into answers, thanks

Answer (score 50, accepted):

## 1. Generate Devise controllers so we can modify it

```
rails g devise:controllers
```

[image]

Now we have all controllers in the *app/controllers/[model] **directory***

## 2. Edit routes.rb

Let's set Devise to use our modified SessionsController

First add this code (of course **change :users** to your devise model) into **config/routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  sessions: 'users/sessions'
}
```

## 3. Modify sessions_controller.rb

[image]

Find the create method and change it to

```
def create
  resource = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:user][:email])
  return invalid_login_attempt unless resource

  if resource.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
    sign_in :user, resource
    return render nothing: true
  end

  invalid_login_attempt
 end
```

Create new method after **protected**

```
def invalid_login_attempt
  set_flash_message(:alert, :invalid)
  render json: flash[:alert], status: 401
end
```

## 4. devise.rb

Insert this into **config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
config.navigational_formats = ["*/*", :html, :json]
```

## 5. Invalid email or password message

Insert a new message into **config/locales/devise.en.yml** under the **sessions**

```
invalid: "Invalid email or password."
```

[image: sessions]

## 6. View

```
= form_for resource, url: session_path(:user), remote: true do |f|
  = f.text_field :email
  = f.password_field :password
  = f.label :remember_me do
    Remember me
    = f.check_box :remember_me
  = f.submit value: 'Sign in'

:javascript
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //form id
    $('#new_user')
    .bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr) {
      //function called on status: 200 (for ex.)
      console.log('success');
    })
    .bind("ajax:error", function(evt, xhr, status, error) {
      //function called on status: 401 or 500 (for ex.)
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    });
  });
```

> Important thing **remote: true**

The reason why I am using **status 200 or 401** unlike {status: 'true'} is less data size, so it is much faster and cleaner.

## Explanation

On signing in, you get these data in params

```
action: "create"
commit: "Sign in"
controller: "users/sessions"
user: {
  email: "test@test.cz"
  password: "123"
  remember_me: "0"
}
utf8: "✓"
```

Before signing, you need to authorize the user.

```
resource = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:user][:email])
```

[User.find_for_database_authentication](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/diaspora/diaspora/User.find_for_database_authentication)

If user is found, resource will be filled with something like

```
created_at: "2015-05-29T12:48:04.000Z"
email: "test@test.cz"
id: 1
updated_at: "2015-06-13T19:56:54.000Z"
```

Otherwise will be

```
null
```

If the user is authenticated, we are about to validate his password

```
if resource.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
```

And finally sign in

```
sign_in :user, resource
```

## Sources

[SessionsController](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb)

Helped me
[Andreas Lyngstad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758288/ruby-devise-sessionscontroller-create-json-getting-nameerror-undefined-bui)

Comment: I have a model for sign in but when the password is incorrect, I get redirected to a backup sign in page. Instead I want the model to simply update with the error. Would I have to use what you've done above to accomplish this?

Comment: very well explained, almost like a blog post.  thanks

Comment: @the_ousek extremely helpful. thank you for coming back and posting.

Comment: Note that this overwrites ALL devise sign ins. You'll want to `respond_to` format if you want to allow other types of sign ins

Comment: Great answer. But `render nothing: true` does not work in Rails 5. It should be changed to `render body: nil`.

Comment: Awsome solution save lot of time to set up ajax signin