# Handling errors and flash messages when using ajax form in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I am using devise, submitting all devise forms like sign up, login, forgot password forms in ajax way by adding remote: true.
How I can handle displaying error messages and flash messages.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you out?

[Devise - Sign In with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829225/devise-sign-in-with-ajax)

Basically, you would send a `401` or similar status back with the response, then handle the error inside your ajax error function.  From there you could append to a DOM element and style accordingly.

Comment: For all the actions like registrations, sessions, forgot password, resend confirmation do i need to do the same?

Comment: I’d think you would approach it the same way. You just have to handle errors manually based on the response http status, as opposed to letting devise do it for you.